# How can we tell our script to wait for an element till it find , if it may take one day to visible in selenium

Tags: selenium

How can we tell our script to wait for an element till it find , if it may take one day to visible in selenium

I have a scenario in my application to tell my script to wait for an element till it find ,it may take couple of hours to one day to visible.

how can i achieve this,

Comment: Share your research please !!!

Comment: what type of application is this that it might take one day to load element. Ask developer to fix it first before you do automation.

Comment: This application is linked to other system and in that system they have to approve the status to find  the element here

Answer (score 0):

You can import and use the Explicit wait using Expect Conditions.

For e.g when using python:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
```

More details from the following:
[Selenium Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit wait. Java code for explicit wait in Selenium WebDriver:

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath of the element)));
```

You can also use id, className or cssSelector for the element you are inspecting.

Though you can use this, it does not seem right to keep the driver waiting for hours, just for an element to be visible. You said other system has to approve status for the element to be visible in your system, try to look for an alternative way to implement this process.